# How to parse a list of String obtained via select box in a REST

Tags: java, html, spring, rest, jhipster

I have this method that creates an object **Event** on my database by getting data from an HTML form.

```
@PostMapping("/events")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<Event> createEvent(@RequestBody Event event) throws URISyntaxException {
    //some code
}
```

My **Event** entity has these attributes:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "jhi_date")
private LocalDate date;

@Column(name = "attendees")
private String attendees;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(unique = true)
private Desk refTable;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "event")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<CustomUser> participants = new HashSet<>();
```

The one that interests me is **attendees**. Due to my business logic I can not change its type from **String** to a **List**.

My answer is: how can I get a List of strings using a **multiple select** in HTML if my model doesn't have a field of type **List**?

I would like to receive a List from HTML and then convert it into one string.

Just to know, I am using Jhipster. Thanks in advice for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This where using [JHipster DTO option](https://jhipster.github.io/using-dtos/) makes a lot of sense as the DTO will adapt `Event` entity data to a format easier to process by the client code.

You can enable it by editing`.jhipster/Event.json` to set `"dto": "mapstruct",` and re-generate your entity with `yo jhipster:entity`.

Comment: I had an idea, could I do something like `@PostMapping("/events")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<Event> createEvent(@RequestBody Event event, @RequestParam(value="attendeesToParse") List<String> participants) throws URISyntaxException` ?